# Map JSON in Angular 9

Tags: json, angular, api

I designed an app using Angular which is linked to a DB using a backEnd made with ASP.NET
My problem is that my JSON in the Front is a little different that the JSON in the backEnd.
And I need help on how to map the frontEnd JSON to send it to the backEnd.

psd: i created all the interfaces on the frontend, and I'm usign formControls and FormArrays to store the data in the front, the problem is that de JSON are a bit different.
I cannot change the JSON on the backEnd because is linked with the DB and it has PK and FK so that's the reasson because it's a bit different.
I was thinking about doing something like this.myform.value and map to the other interface, but i have no idea on how to do that because i have array of arrays...
Maybe a for loop?

Here is my frontEnd JSON:

```
{
  "non-array fields....................." : "bla bla",
  "arraySustancias": [
    {
      "sustanciaActiva": "hello",
      "contenido": "2",
      "suministro": ["hello2","hello3"],
      "unidades": "3"
    }
  ],


      "arrayProcedimientos": [
    {
      "procedimiento": "",
      "fechaInicioProcedimiento": "",
      "fechaFinProcedimiento": "",
      "notasProcedimiento": "",
      "arraySubprocedimientos": [
        {
          "subprocedimiento": "",
          "fechaInicioSubProcedimiento": "",
          "fechaFinSubProcedimiento": "",
          "notasSubProcedimiento": "",
          "exp": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my backEnd JSON:

```
{
  "non-array fields.....................": "bla bla",
  "registros_arraySustancias": [
    {
      "registros_arraySustancias_suministro": [
        {
          "registros_arraySustancias_id": "",
          "id": "",
          "value": [
            "ABBOTT LABORATORIES",
            "ADAMA Agan Ltd."
          ]
        }
      ],
      "registros_id": "",
      "id": "",
      "sustanciaActiva": "hola",
      "contenido": 2,
      "unidades": 3
    }
  ],
  "registros_arrayProcedimientos": [
    {
      "registros_id": "",
      "id": "",
      "procedimiento": "text",
      "fechaInicioProcedimiento": "18/06/2020",
      "fechaFinProcedimiento": "18/06/2020",
      "notasProcedimiento": "notes",
      "registros_arrayProcedimientos_arraySubprocedimientos": [
        {
          "registros_arrayProcedimientos_id": "",
          "id": "",
          "subprocedimiento": "text",
          "fechaInicioSubProcedimiento": "19/06/2020",
          "fechaFinSubProcedimiento": "19/06/2020",
          "notasSubProcedimiento": "notes"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: all the field named "id" or "_id" are the PK and FK, they are autoincrement and does not need to have value.

Comment: I mean, what's the question here? Where do you get that JSON from? Either you can change the format generated, or you'll simply have to write a function that converts this. In TypeScript/JavaScript, you can just have the JSON as an object and then you have to assign that to a differently structured object. What do you want us to do, write that line by line for you?

Comment: not all the code I have the theory on how to do that, I just need like a little example or similar on how to do that.
@BenjaminMaurer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply create an object from your original object. There is no magic or automatic way to do that. Example:

```
interface OriginalData {
    foo: string;
    baz: {
        test: number[]
    };
}

interface MyData {
    foobar: string;
    bazTest: number[];
}

function getData(): Observable<OriginalData> {
  return this.http.get<OriginalData>(url);
}

function convertData(original: OriginalData): MyData {
    const res: MyData = {
        foobar: original.foo,
        bazTest: original.baz.test
    };

    return res;
}

// somewhere in your code
getData().subscribe(
    v => sendData(convertData(v))
);
```

I'm using the Angular http client here, because you added the tag "angular". It will give you an object of the type you specified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what happens when you have an array of arrays?
Could you show an example?

Comment: Honestly, this question is very low quality. I don't know what you want to achieve. Now reading your other comments, you actually generate the json with a form before sending it to the backend? Then why even transform it, if you generate it? You could just create the right nested structure in your form! And now you ask me about nested arrays - ok, so what? Nested arrays transformed to what? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Basically I needed something that is solved with your answer.
Maybe my question was bad asked.
And my 2nd questions related to nested arrays was this solution:

`registros_arraySustancias: [{
        unidades: "",
        contenido: 2,
        sustanciaActiva: "",
        registros_arraySustancias_suministro: [{value: [""]}]
      }
      ]`

Answer (score 1):

In that case I think you have to work a little bit with angular forms so that data from frontend should be from the same structure. FormGroups and FormArayys will help you alot. 
Try looking at this article as well. 
http://www.howilearnt.com/web-development/angular/make-a-json-object-with-angular-forms/

Comment: Hi, all the form was made using formgroups and formarrays

Comment: Yeah and that would be easy to manage. You can modify your data according to the structure of json after `this.myForm.value`. But that needs alot of looping and conditions. You can check `lodash` for that. 
But going with angular forms is the best choice

Answer (score 0):

That was what I was looking for:

```
mapeado = {
pais: "",
registros_arraySustancias: [{
unidades: "",
contenido: 2,
sustanciaActiva: "",
registros_arraySustancias_suministro: [{value: [""]}]
}
]
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help